# Mysql sort by date not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

I am pulling records out of my mysql database using php and want to order them by a database field called expdate.

The dates for the reminders are stored in the table in this format 17-04-12 as varchar.

I am using the following code to pull all the records out and order them by the expdate column.

```
    <table border="0" style="text-align:left;">
      <tr style="text-align:left;">
        <th style="text-align:left;" width="200px"  scope="col">Name</th>
        <th style="text-align:left;" width="200px"  scope="col">Email</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;" width="200px" scope="col">Telephone</th>
      <th style="text-align:left;" width="200px" scope="col">Current Cover Expires</th>
      </tr>
    <?php
    $today = date("d-m-y");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ymeg_chronoforms_data_NewsletterSubscribe ORDER BY expdate")or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<tr style="text-align:left;">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
        echo '<td style="text-align:left;">';  
      echo $row['name'];
      echo '</td>'; 
      echo '<td style="text-align:left;">'; 
      echo $row['email'];
         echo '</td>'; 
    echo '<td style="text-align:left;">'; 
      echo $row['tel'];
         echo '</td>'; 
     echo '<td style="text-align:left;">'; 
      echo $row['expdate'];
        echo '</td>'; 
      echo "</tr>";
      }

      ?>


    </table>
```

The problem is, the columns are being sorted quite randomly, it outputs the records and sorts them by this date order :

```
08-07-12
17-05-12
17-05-13
```

Comment: Why don't you store the dates in any appropriate format?

Comment: this is how my javascript datepicker outputs the dates when picked

Comment: That looks right to me. It's ordering chars, after all.

Comment: stop storing the dates as varchar for Buddha's sake, what's wrong with the multiple date specific field types.

Comment: I really hope you made it as an example. You have there HTML + CSS + PHP + SQL .. you are missing only JavaScript for the perfect storm of spaghetti code

Comment: @Iain Simpson: "this is how my javascript datepicker outputs the dates when picked" -- you can parse it and store as a `date`

Comment: my js date picker knows that human readable and db storage is not the same thing, and can return one format while showing humans another.

Comment: I see no sort by date, I see sort by char, seems to be spot on as well. You need to learn this one to avoid regularly daft mistakes like this "08-07-12" is not a date, it's a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
order by STR_TO_DATE(expdate, '%d-%m-%y')
```

(and next time use real Date format... for Date datas ;) )

Comment: @Iain Simpson: actually it's not perfect, it is just a temporary solution until you rewrite it in a proper way

Comment: @IainSimpson : the best thing to do would be to use this function to populate the new "RealExpDate" field of your Database ;)

Answer (score 1):

Store the dates in the proper date format inside MySQL. It would be best to rearrange the format produced by the datepicker and then store the rearranged date properly inside MySQL. This should solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

need to use a data convertion:

```
$today  = date("d-m-y");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ymeg_chronoforms_data_NewsletterSubscribe ORDER BY  STR_TO_DATE(expdate,'%d-%m-%Y')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this is well ordered, I can confirm that the 12th of july 2008 comes before the 12th of may 2017, which also comes before the 13th of may 2017...

You have to specify a specific format to your selected date i guess

- expdate is a VARCHAR: Like other members said, use STR_TO_DATE(expdate, '%d/%m/%Y')
- expdate is a DATE: use DATE_FORMAT(expdate, '%d/%m/%Y')

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ymeg_chronoforms_data_NewsletterSubscribe ORDER BY expdate DESC")or die(mysql_error());
```

use ASC= ascendent

use DESC= descendent